# Unable to draw a Curved Polyline using Here Maps JS Api

Tags: here-api, heremaps

Unable to Draw a curved polyline using Here Maps JS API.

Trying to add the logic based on my previous findings.

It throws an error "**Uncaught TypeError: arc.GreatCircle is not a constructor**"

Any Suggestions on how to fix this ?

[My Earlier Querstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73367267/how-to-draw-a-curved-line-between-two-points-using-here-maps)

Here is my working JSFiddle which is trying to draw a curve to multiple spots.

```js
//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:52, lng:5},
  zoom: 5,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
window.addEventListener('resize', function() { map.getViewPort().resize(); });
var npoints = 100, 
        offset = 20;
 

// Now use the map as required...
//addPolylineToMap(map);
// Berlin -> Chicago0
    add([52.51607,13.37699],[41.88425,-87.63245], { style: { strokeColor : "#00FF00", lineWidth : 5, lineDash: [3], lineHeadCap: "arrow-head", lineTailCap: "arrow-tail"} });
    
    // Tokyo -> san Francisco
    add([35.68019,139.81194],[37.77712,-122.41964], {style: { strokeColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.7)", lineWidth: 15, lineDash: [1], lineHeadCap: "arrow-head", lineTailCap: "arrow-tail"} });
    
    // Berlin -> Melbourne
    add([52.51607,13.37699],[-37.81753,144.96715], { style: { strokeColor : "rgba(255,0,255,0.7)", lineWidth : 5, lineDash: [3], lineHeadCap: "arrow-head", lineTailCap: "arrow-tail"} });
    
    // Berlin -> Paris -> Paris -> London
    add([52.51607,13.37699],[48.85721, 2.34144], { style: { strokeColor : "rgba(0,255,0,0.7)", lineWidth : 5, lineDash: [3], lineHeadCap: "arrow-head", lineTailCap: "arrow-tail"} });
    add([48.85721, 2.34144],[51.50643,-0.12721], { style: { strokeColor : "rgba(255,255,0,0.7)", lineWidth : 5, lineDash: [3], lineHeadCap: "arrow-head", lineTailCap: "arrow-tail"} });
    
    function add(s,e,options) {
   var arc = {};
arc.Coord = Coord;
arc.Arc = Arc;
arc.GreatCircle = GreatCircle;
        var start_ll = new H.geo.Point(s[0],s[1]),
            end_ll = new H.geo.Point(e[0],e[1]),
            start_coord = {x: start_ll.lng, y:start_ll.lat},
            end_coord = {x:end_ll.lng, y:end_ll.lat};
            description = ''+s[0]+','+s[1]+'=>'+e[0]+','+e[1]+'',
            gc0 = new arc.GreatCircle(start_coord,end_coord, {'name': 'line', 'color':'#ff7200','description':description}),
            line0 = gc0.Arc(npoints,{offset:offset}),
            strip = line0.strip();
        
        map.addObject(new H.map.Polyline(strip, options));
    }
var D2R = Math.PI / 180;
var R2D = 180 / Math.PI;


var Coord = function(lon, lat) {
    this.lon = lon;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.x = D2R * lon;
    this.y = D2R * lat;
};

Coord.prototype.view = function() {
    return String(this.lon).slice(0, 4) + ',' + String(this.lat).slice(0, 4);
};

Coord.prototype.antipode = function() {
    var anti_lat = -1 * this.lat;
    var anti_lon = (this.lon < 0) ? 180 + this.lon : (180 - this.lon) * -1;
    return new Coord(anti_lon, anti_lat);
};

var LineString = function() {
    this.coords = [];
    this.length = 0;
};

LineString.prototype.move_to = function(coord) {
    this.length++;
    this.coords.push(coord);
};

var Arc = function(properties) {
    this.properties = properties || {};
    this.geometries = [];
};

Arc.prototype.json = function() {
    if (this.geometries.length <= 0) {
        return { 'geometry': { 'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': null }, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': this.properties };
    } else if (this.geometries.length == 1) {
        return { 'geometry': { 'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': this.geometries[0].coords }, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': this.properties };
    } else {
        var multiline = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.geometries.length; i++) {
            multiline.push(this.geometries[i].coords);
        }
        return { 'geometry': { 'type': 'MultiLineString', 'coordinates': multiline }, 'type': 'Feature', 'properties': this.properties };
    }
};

Arc.prototype.strip = function() {
    var s = H.geo.Strip ? new H.geo.Strip() : new H.geo.LineString();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.geometries.length; i++) {
        if (this.geometries[i].coords.lenght !== 0) {
            var coords = this.geometries[i].coords;
            for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
                var p = new H.geo.Point(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]);
                s.pushPoint(p);
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
 var GreatCircle = function(start, end, properties) {
    if (!start || start.x === undefined || start.y === undefined) {
        throw new Error("GreatCircle constructor expects two args: start and end objects with x and y properties");
    }
    if (!end || end.x === undefined || end.y === undefined) {
        throw new Error("GreatCircle constructor expects two args: start and end objects with x and y properties");
    }
    this.start = new Coord(start.x, start.y);
    this.end = new Coord(end.x, end.y);
    this.properties = properties || {};

    var w = this.start.x - this.end.x;
    var h = this.start.y - this.end.y;
    var z = Math.pow(Math.sin(h / 2.0), 2) + Math.cos(this.start.y) * Math.cos(this.end.y) * Math.pow(Math.sin(w / 2.0), 2);
    this.g = 2.0 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(z));

    if (this.g == Math.PI) {
        throw new Error('it appears ' + start.view() + ' and ' + end.view() + " are 'antipodal', e.g diametrically opposite, thus there is no single route but rather infinite");
    } else if (isNaN(this.g)) {
        throw new Error('could not calculate great circle between ' + start + ' and ' + end);
    }
};
```

```css
#map {
    width: 95%;
    height: 450px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://heremaps.github.io/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/test-credentials.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Polyline on the Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../template.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src='../test-credentials.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="markers-on-the-map">
    
    <div id="map"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src='demo.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple: the var GreatCircle is not defined yet but program code invoke GreatCircle
We moved some parts of code through each together

but any way there is error GreatCircle doesn't have 'arc' property defined.

there is this module https://demo.support.here.com/javascripts/examples/v31/geodesic-polyline.js
but you needs Bézier curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve
I found some implementation on this https://habr.com/ru/post/163073/ - (but in russian) - there a curve consists from lines based on 100 points (step 0.01)
flow = getBezierCurve(new Array(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]), 0.01);
drawLines(ctx, flow, 10);

In JS API wasn't implemented functionality of like Bézier curve
but search in google on "bezier curve javascript example code" - if you get points of curve you can use in JS API map.screenToGeo every point and plot it on the map